# iPad/Safari Facebook Login Photo Verification

Tags: facebook, ipad, security, safari

All,

I work with a social media company and recently experienced something very vexing at a live event.

We have visitors sign in temporarily on iPad kiosks for registration purposes to their facebook account (via Safari).

Unfortunately, I am not within proximity/access of our iPads at present and won't be until the next live event. I am hoping to not have to sneak out and buy/borrow an iPad just to get to the bottom of this.

Basically when we use my company's iPads (which were set up a few months back prior to me joining the company), Facebook login works just fine. User inputs username/password, hits login, they are immediately prompted to authorize our application. However, when we use the third party's iPads, almost every single time, Facebook initiates an unregistered device issue and forces the captcha + Photo Verification/ID process in order to complete the login process.

I did a variety of tests that ensured this was in no way related to a) our ISP/IP; b) our Facebook app c) incorrect credentials being entered; d) individual account security settings. The jist of those tests centered around using the same account on one of my company's iPads, then one of the third party's iPads. I've narrowed it down to being a local device setting, I think. However, I did not have time to go through the iPad + Safari settings such as private browsing etc.

As a QA person, I am fully aware that my next step would have been to compare the settings of our functional iPads to theirs which end up with the verification issue. That being said, all the equipment had to be packed up and sent on the road before I could complete my testing.

So, if anyone has specific experience related to this sort of issue (Facebook login verification) I'd really appreciate any tips that you can provide to make sure users are not prompted for excessive security verifications, as it slows down our registration process in an unacceptable manner.

Kindly, Dave

Comment: Couple of things. If a user has never used Safari on the iPad before, then there may be a login verification, especially if the user has [Login Approvals](https://www.facebook.com/help/148233965247823/) enabled.  Also, if the iPads (or users) have moved to a new geographical location since the last login, then the location change will almost always trigger a login verification.  This is to prevent user accounts from being compromised by locations that are not their home/work/etc.

Comment: @DonnLee Login Approvals was not it. I tested that on a couple accounts to see if it could cause it. I also am not certain about geographical location either, as I had someone use the same account with no security to login on our ipad and then the client's. The issue didn't occur on ours, but did on the client ipad. 

I suppose the issue could be due to the ISP we were using was routing via the UK rather than somewhere in Norway, where the event was happening. Possibility?

Comment: Yes. Facebook probably thought the local users (Norway) were logging in from the UK.  Imagine you are one of those users: You just used FB at home before the event (FB knows that), then a few minutes later FB sees you trying to login from the UK.  Facebook is obviously going to make you confirm it is really you.  Next time, it would be safer to use a local ISP with local IP addresses for these local users.